Mac menu bar app crashing on app launch as notarized app only: failed to get text offset for /Applications/... (#3) No such process
I am developing a macos menu bar app, and for some reason, when I archive, notarize & export the app to my Applications folder and run the app, it crashes instantly. When I use the Console app, I see the following error messages:
myapp[30188]: AppSandbox request successful

Channel could not return listener port.

activating connection: mach=false listener=false peer=false name=com.apple.hiservices-xpcservice

activating connection: mach=true listener=false peer=false name=com.apple.window_proxies

invalidated because the current process cancelled the connection by calling xpc_connection_cancel()

[app<application.com.myapp.15235459.15235465(501)>:30188] termination reported by launchd (2, 5, 5)

failed to fetch /Applications/myapp.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeRequirements-1 error=-10

failed to get text offset for /Applications/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp[30188]: (#3) No such process

RBSStateCapture remove item called for untracked item 378-345-52811 (target:[app<application.com.myapp.15235459.15235465(501)>:30188])

When I run the app in Xcode (in debug mode & release mode), there are no Warning messages except this one for Sparkle (I am relatively sure it is unrelated to my issue but including here for brevity):
Warning: Background app automatically schedules for update checks but does not implement gentle reminders. As a result, users may not take notice to update alerts that show up in the background. Please visit https://sparkle-project.org/documentation/gentle-reminders for more information. This warning will only be logged once.

Here is a link to the .app file binary.
I gave my app's binary to a friend and faced these error messages in Console app, but I have not been able to reproduce them myself.
Sandbox: myapp(9044) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/user/Downloads/myapp.app

IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTION: Failed to copy signing info for 9044, responsible for /private/var/folders/nt/40hq8tkx0tgb7c4fw5_n79wr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/345F7E81-EE9E-4ADF-A66F-589A6647291D/d/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp: #-67065: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-67065 "(null)"

I have tried the following to stop the app from crashing, all to no avail:

Clean Xcode
Delete Xcode Derived Data
Restart Mac
Build app with an alternative bundle identifier
Removed Sparkle package and re-archived, notarized app
Enable App Sandbox in Xcode Project > Target > Signing
Added com.apple.security.automation.apple-events to app entitlements file
Replaced the 'Developer ID Application Certificate' from Keychain with a newly generated certificate
Use Xcode Manual Signing instead of automatic. (Create dev, release provisioning profiles, app id)

Additional context

Xcode 15.2
MacOS Sonoma 14.5
Xcode minimum deployment: 13.0

Package Dependancies:

LaunchAtLogin (main branch)
RNCryptor (5.1.0)
Sparkle (2.6.3)


Your linked app was deleted, btw.

Your deployment target is macOS 13+, you should use LaunchAtLogin-Modern

I use Launch at Login myself so im sure that's not the problem.
This apple dev forum thread has the same error but minimally different NSOSStatusErrorDomain code. I assume it is a very similar problem as you have.
According to the DTS Engineer that is a signing problem. Please have a read in case you haven't seen it: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/678816
Personal Experience:
Im not sure what kind of problem you have but:

Are you sure you take the correct app file. After notarisation, the app file that was created with the archive operation is not notarised, but a new notarized app file is generated. It is generated in the same bundle within a cryptic folder name
You need hardened runtime capability for ad hoc distribution with notarisation outside of the App Store. Did you check if you have this? See following docs for a full list of requirements for notarisation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/#3087727


After viewing Console app > Crash Reports, I found that my app was crashing when unwrapping a null value. The value was null as I have only just discovered that in release archives for .app bundles, Xcode scheme environment variables are not passed to the app.
The answer was much simpler than I initially thought and was not related to any signing issues.
